# Reducing the size of the training data

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning

My problem is that running `Classify` on my training data takes too long.

First I get 50,000 images such as car, cat, dog, hat, train, etc.

```
data = ResourceObject["CIFAR-100"];
ts = ResourceData[data, "TrainingData"];
```

Then I try

```
Classify[ts]
```

but it takes too long.

I probably need to preprocess the training data test set to reduce its size before calling `Classify`. What is good way to do that?

Comment: ImageResize+RandomSample+Limit the number of classes